# How to kill application in ti-zen web application

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

In ti-zen web application when i tried to kill application using kill API applications are not killing. i added privileges in config file. (tizen.application.kill(context id).

`HTTP://tizen.org/privilege/application.kill` is added in config file

Answer (score 4):

You can 'kill' the Application:

```
tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
```

without any privilegs

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually kill the app at the command line if needed.

wrt-launcher -k

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the application you can write `tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();` where ever you want without any privileges.